# If I make a copy of a system partition, can I safely delete the original?

Tags: partitioning, windows-10, system-reserved-partition, partition-copy

I want to merge 2 non-adjacent partitions. Since partitions need to be adjacent to be merged with disk partitioning tools, I plan to create a copy of the partition that is in between the ones I want to merge and then delete it.

From left to right, the lineup is regular storage partition, System Partition (created during Windows 10 installation), and Boot Partition (contains the Windows 10 OS). If I copy the System Partition into unallocated space to the left of the regular storage partition, can I safely delete the original System Partition? Meaning that it shouldn't cause any kind of system errors?

Note: To make the copy of the system partition, I will be using EaseUS Partition Master.

This is what I have:
[image]

This is what I plan to do:
[image]

Comment: Just give us a screenshot.  A picture is worth a thousand technical accurate words.

Comment: @Ramhound I added two screenshots